# Count files that created or updated today in a directory

Tags: php, file

Given a path to a directory, how can I count how many files in it were created or updated today using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$cTime = new DateTime();
$fTime = new DateTime();
foreach (glob('./*') as $item) {
    if (!is_dir($item)) {
        $fTime->setTimestamp(filemtime($item));
        if ($cTime->diff($fTime)->days < 2) {
            echo $item . PHP_EOL;
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```